# Client side cache busting using the CLI

Tags: aurelia

We're using the `aurelia-cli`. The tasks include these:

```
build.json
build.ts
process-css.ts
process-markup.ts
process-sass.ts
run.json
run.ts
test.json
test.ts
transpile.ts
```

How if at all do we do a cache-busting solution the with cli?

What we've tried already is to increment the number of the `scripts` directory, so that it goes `scripts1`, `scripts2`, `scriptsN`.

Comment: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## 0.20.0 Support

It's my lucky day. [An `aurelia-cli` release from 8 hours](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/releases/tag/0.20.0) ago says this:

> Features: Support bundle revision numbers

## Walkthru

First, install 0.20.0 and create a new app.

```
npm install aurelia-cli@">=0.20.0" -g
au new my-app
```

Or, upgrade an existing app.

```
npm install aurelia-cli@">=0.20.0" --save-dev
```

Next, open `my-app/aurelia-project/aurelia.json`.

Set the `build.options.rev` property to true.

```
"options": {
   "minify": "stage & prod",
   "sourcemaps": "dev & stage", 
   "rev": true
},
```

Set the `output` and `index` properties inside the `build.targets`

```
"targets": [
    {
      "id": "web",
      "displayName": "Web",
      "output": "scripts",
      "index": "index.html"
    }
 ],
```

The `aurelia-cli` will look for the `index` file and replace the reference to `scripts\vendor-bundle.js` like this:

```
<script src="scripts\vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper">
<script src="scripts\vendor-bundle-947c308e28.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper">
```

Finally, build the app.

```
au build --env prod
```

Your bundles will look something like this:

```
app-bundle-e0c4d46f7d.js
vendor-bundle-dba9184d78.js
```

## Source on GitHub

[cli/lib/build/bundler.js](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/blob/f43f189083d990f49fa426eebffb0c0f1ec43b38/lib/build/bundler.js)

```
let defaultBuildOptions = {
  minify: "stage & prod",
  sourcemaps: "dev & stage",
  rev: false
};
```

[cli/lib/build/bundler.js](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/blob/f43f189083d990f49fa426eebffb0c0f1ec43b38/lib/build/bundle.js)

```
if (buildOptions.rev) {
  //Generate a unique hash based off of the bundle contents
  this.hash = generateHash(concat.content);
  bundleFileName = generateHashedPath(this.config.name, this.hash);       
}
```

Comment: You have one additional step that you don't need. You only need to add the `"index"` property to the build targets, not the platform. Glad that works for you! Also, feel free to mark your own answer as *the* answer :)

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. Updated.

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as *the* answer, that way others can see it solved :)

Comment: For me this answer failed until I revised the setting of **build.options.rev** to the boolean true (not the string "true"). Then things worked as expected. I'm running cli version 0.22.0 FWIW.

Comment: As @KevinM said, I also had to remove the quotes and use literal true for this to work. Otherwise it worked like charm!

Comment: To keep filenames unchanged when developing, change `"rev": true` to `"rev": "stage & prod"`.

Answer (score 2):

My Aurelia app is hosted in an ASP.Net Core MVC page, and I have had good success using the ASP.Net Core `asp-append-version` tag helper to ensure that browsers load updated JS bundles correctly.

This attribute can be added to script tags, and ASP.Net will automatically append a version # based on the script file's contents.  The hash is generated when the application starts, so the application must be restarted in order for ASP.Net to detect any new changes.

The trick in getting this to work with Aurelia lies in also adding the app-bundle.js file as a script tag on the hosting page:

`<body aurelia-app="main-public" class="public">
    <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" 
            data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper" 
            asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app-bundle.js" 
            asp-append-version="true"></script>
</body>`

The output looks something like this:

`<body aurelia-app="main-public" class="public">
    <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js?v=97hNIHUQnLL3Q44m2FWNV-3NIpgqvgIDIx5sUXUcySQ" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app-bundle.js?v=htYOQIr-GHrpZIDiT2b32LxxPZs10cfUU4YNt9iKLro"></script>
</body>`

*Disclaimer:* I haven't inspected the vendor-bundle.js source code with regard to the loading behavior of app-bundle.js, so I don't know how robust this solution is.  I have not encountered any issues with this approach, and it is working well for my scenario; however, please use with caution and test adequately before applying to production code.

Comment: I'm looking at doing something similar. Generally you only need to include the target bundle (default is vendor-bundle), and it looks as though a script tag is generated (by requireJS, maybe?) and inserted into the head for the app-bundle. Are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: Just tried this. Looks like if you do what you're ooing, requireJS doesn't have to load the script itself and so doesn't insert the script into the HEAD! Nice!

Comment: That is correct.  However, if you add the script tag manually, it uses that one instead and doesn't try to load the script twice.

Comment: Yeah. It seems as though you probably don't need your disclaimer. :-)

Comment: Maybe not. I just don't know the underlying mechanism of how it happens to work, so my concern is that there's a potential race condition that might pop up at some point and end up loading from require JS even though tag is already on the page.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I'm doing something similar in PHP. The index.html is replaced with index.php and i just append the file mtime of the scripts to the script src attribute. Then whenever the scripts get updated, the links automatically change.