# Aurelia CLI not calling correct app file when cache busting

Tags: aurelia

When I run the **au new**, with **options.rev** set to **true** (basically, this: [Client side cache busting using the CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651190/client-side-cache-busting-using-the-cli)).  It rebuilds the files (vendor-bundle-xxxxx.js and app-bundle-xxxx.js), but the vendor-bundle file is still calling app-bundle.js instead of the new file.  The app-bundle.js file is either still cached or returns a 404, making the cache busting essentially irrelevant.  I'm unable to find any docs or support that address this issue.  If anyone has any idea how I might fix this, I'd appriciate hearing it.

Comment: Did you set the index property inside the build.targets? "targets": [
    {
      "id": "web",
      "displayName": "Web",
      "output": "scripts",
      "index": "index.html"
    }
 ],

Comment: I did, yes.  Thanks.